# how to concatenate/assemble the alias name of some bash cli commands

Tags: string, bash, alias

I have the following aliases in `.bash_aliases`

```
ssh51ro="ssh -p12345 root@192.168.15.71" 
ssh52ro="ssh -p12345 root@192.168.8.25"
ssh53ro="ssh -p12345 root@192.168.35.33"
...
ssh59ro="ssh -p12345 root@192.168.1.9"
```

I wonder if I can send the same command to multiple recipients in a for loop. I would normally increment an "i" variable and concatenate the name of the alias together.

```
for i in $( seq 1 9 ) ; do ssh5${i}ro date; done
```

But this doesn't seem to work. it says specifically that "ssh5*i*ro command is not found".

How can I assemble and run the commands in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not store commands in variables. Use functions.

```
myssh() { ssh -p12345 root@"$@"; }
ssh51ro() { myssh 192.168.15.71 "$@"; }
ssh52ro() { myssh 192.168.8.25 "$@"; }
...
for i in $( seq 1 9 ) ; do ssh5${i}ro date; done
# maybe you want dynamic list of functions based on naming pattern:
for func in $(compgen -A function | grep ssh5.ro); do "$func" date; done
```

You may want to research Ansible and Puppet Bolt.